# Installing Firefox Beta, and not replacing stable Firefox

Tags: firefox

I want to test beta version of Firefox but i don't want to replace the stable version. However the .deb firefox beta have same package name, so it replaces old version. Is there a way to install both beta and stable versions?

Answer (score 5):

You could just grab the current beta from http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/beta/, extract to to your home folder, and then run it.

At the time of writing, the current beta is 24.0b4,

- download it to your home folder (after that you should have `firefox-24.0b4.tar.bz2` in you home folder)
- right click it, select Extract Here
- close firefox if it's been open
- run the beta with `firefox/firefox`